# Django app, wordpress blog, apache 301 canonical redirection -> why do I have infinite loop?

Tags: apache, wordpress, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I have a django app at / (served by WSGI), and a wordpress blog at /blog/. I'm trying to setup a 301 redirection from example.com to www.example.com, and managed to do so, except the wordpress blog. Reaching the blog triggers an infinite redirect loop.

Apache configuration at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.example.com
   DocumentRoot /srv/www/example.com/public_html/
   Alias /blog "/srv/www/example.com/public_html"
</VirtualHost>
```

The wordpress blog has a .htaccess in the root directory /srv/www/example.com/public_html:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What is the behaviour without the Redirect permanent? Looping too?

Comment: Working for me without the Redirect permanent rule. And /blog/index.php MUST exist or else it triggers loop and error 500.

Comment: No problem without redirect permanent. It's caused by a conflict between 2 configurations it seems. /blog/index.php is the wordpress index.php, and it's there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out why the server was giving infinite redirect.

Wordpress blog was configured (in settings) at example.com. So it would internally rewrite the URL from www.example.com/blog to example.com/blog. At this point my redirect (example.com -> www.example.com) would kick in, sending an infinite loop.

Solution was simply to set the site at 'www.example.com' and not 'example.com'. The configuration was correct.